# Differentiable at the orgin and plot of a function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My first question is:

1) Is $f(x,y)=\dfrac {xy(x^{2}-y^{2})}{{(x^{2}+y^{2})}^{3/2}}$ differntiable at $(0,0)$?

Considering polar co-ordinates: $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$.

$$\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow f(x,y) &= \frac {r\cos \theta r\sin \theta (r^{2}\cos ^{2}\theta-r^{2}\sin ^{2}\theta)}{{(r^{2}\cos ^{2}\theta+r^{2}\sin ^{2}\theta)}^{3/2}} \\
\\
&= \frac {r^{4}\cos\theta\sin\theta(\cos ^{2}\theta-\sin ^{2}\theta)}{r^{3}} \\
\\
&= r\cos\theta\sin\theta(\cos ^{2}\theta-\sin ^{2}\theta)
\end{align*}$$

Hence linear in $r$. Therefore there doesn't exist a unique tangent plane at $(0,0)$. Therefore $f(x,y)$ is not differentiable there.

2) Considering $$f(x,y)= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\dfrac {x^{3}y}{x^{6}+y^{2}} & \text{if }(x,y) \neq 0, \\
\\
0 & \text{if }(x,y)=(0,0).
\end{array}\right.$$

If you were to plot the function $\theta \mapsto f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ what might the plot look like. Justify your answer.

I am bit unsure on what this plot would be and the reason. I'm guessing at the crinkle function?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1)$ It is not differentiable at (0,0). The function does not exist at this point. When you plug in (0,0) you get$\frac{0}{0}$ which is undefined. If you are still not convinced you can take the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and with respect to $y$ and plug in (0,0):
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{5 x^2 y^3 - y^5}{(x^2 + y^2)^{5/2}}
\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{x^5 - 5 x^3 y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{5/2}}
$$
Now, plug in (0,0) and again in both cases you will get $\frac{0}{0}$ which means the slope of the tangent line is undefined and $f(x,y)$ is not differentiable at (0,0).

$2)$ I could not come up with a convenient way of plotting $f(x,y)=\frac {x^{3}y}{x^{6}+y^{2}}$ without using any software. The only thing I can say about it is that its domain is $x^6 +y^2>0$. This is how Function $f(rcos \theta,rsin\theta)$ will look like: $$f(rcos \theta,rsin\theta)=\frac{r^4cos^3\theta  sin\theta}{(r^6cos^6\theta + r^2 sin^2\theta)}$$

and its graph:

[image]